# zsh: check exit code of pipeline of commands

Tags: shell, zsh, pipe, exit-status

I have long pipeline of commands in `zsh` script:

```
pv /dev/sda > sda.raw | sha256sum > sda.raw.sha256 | cut -c61-64 | read SHASUM
```

how can I check inside an `if` statement, that all commands exited successfully?

I know about `${pipestatus[@]}`, but it is an array. So I would have to check each element individually.

Is there some shortcut to check that `${pipestatus[@]}` contains only `0` ?

## UPDATE:

I have discovered some weird behavior:

for testing, I set up small filesystem (10MB) so that it fills up quickly:

```
#!/bin/zsh

set -o pipefail

if pv /dev/zero > loop/file ; then
echo OK
else
echo FAIL
fi
```

as expected, I get following error, and "FAIL" printed:

```
pv: write failed: No space left on device
```

However, when I change the pv command just slightly, it suddenly does not print any error, and the pv command seems to run indefinitely (even though there is no space left on the device)

```
#!/bin/zsh

set -o pipefail

if pv /dev/zero > loop/file | sha256sum ; then
echo OK
else
echo FAIL
fi
```

Comment: Set `pipefail` and check `$?`?

Comment: A comment about the pipeline you show: `pv` seems to write to a file via a redirection, meaning `sha256sum` won't ever get anything to process.  Likewise, the output of `sha256sum` is redirected to a file, so even if it produced output, `cut` would never get anything to work with.  Consequently, the final `read` won't do anything as all the data is written to files instead of to the next stage of the pipeline. If the redirections are removed, the `read` might read something into the `SHASUM` variable, but this is not what our question is about.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I think this works in zsh when you enable the multios option

Comment: So it does (sorry for not using my brain). Still, it would be better, for the readability of the question, if the reliance on this feature was either pointed out explicitly or removed in the question.

Comment: Your update is a side effect of multios, and it should be asked as a separate question (`pv` doesn't fail there, so of course there's no failure to detect and so it's a completely different problem than the original question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. set the `pipefail` option from ksh (`set -o pipefail`), then the exit status of a pipeline will be that of the right-most pipeline component that failed.

   ```
   set -o pipefail
   if ! A | B | C; then
     echo at least one of the commands failed.
   fi
   ```
2. look for non-zero values in `$pipestatus`. With the `extendedglob` option enabled, `$pipestatus[(r)^0]` (or `$pipestatus[(r)<1->]` which doesn't require `extendedglob`) will return the exit status of the left-most failing pipeline component and `$pipestatus[(R)^0]` of the right-most, so you can do:

   ```
   set -o extendedglob
   A | B | C
   if (( $pipestatus[(r)^0] )); then
     echo at least one of the commands failed.
   fi
   ```

   or

   ```
   A | B | C
   if (( $pipestatus[(r)<1->] )); then
     echo at least one of the commands failed.
   fi
   ```

   With the `I` subscript flag instead of `r`/`R`, you'll get the `I`ndex of the right-most matching element, so you can do:

   ```
   A | B | C
   if (( failed = $pipestatus[(I)<1->] )); then
     echo component $failed failed.
   fi
   ```

   `${pipestatus:#0}` will expand to the components of `$pipestatus` except 0, so you could also do:

   ```
   A | B | C
   failed_statuses=( ${pipestatus:#0} )
   if (( $#failed_statuses )); then
     echo "${#failed_statuses} command(s) failed. Statuses: $failed_statuses"
   fi
   ```

Comment: this does not seem to work. Could you please look at my updated question?

Comment: @MartinVegter, see muru's comment to your question. With `pv > file | cmd`, since you're redirecting `pv`'s output several times, `pv`'s stdout is not a pipe to a teeing process, not to `cmd`. And that `tee`ing process doesn't die when one of the destinations cannot be written. Same as in `cat /dev/zero > /dev/full > /dev/null`